# Unlogged Reputation Changes?

Tags: support, reputation

I've, on StackOverflow, gone from 16-14 rep (someone downvoted my post,) and then I refreshed to see it go up to 18. It told me that I got +2 from accepting an answer, but it doesn't tell me how I got the other two. Does it log all rep. changes? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at your reputation history, you have never received any downvotes on any of your posts. (at least among the ones that are not deleted)

So in your case:

1. Somebody downvoted your question. -2, (16 -> 14)
2. You accepted an answer. +2, (14 -> 16)
3. The downvoter revoked the downvote. +2, (16 -> 18)

The order of the last two might have been switched in your case. But that doesn't matter. The downvote was revoked in the same day it was cast, so it doesn't appear in your history.